# Why Stack class inherits from Vector class in java?

Tags: java, vector, stack

When I referred to the java class [hierarchy](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/overview-tree.html), I found that the `Vector` class is the parent of the `Stack` class. To me, this seems somehow strange because this allows us to violate the logic of the stack with operations that are inherited, such as `insertElementAt()`, `removeElementAt()`, and so on. These operations violate the discipline of the stack, last in first out. Anyone can help ?

Comment: It's not about what are the features it should not provide. A vector with no insertElementAt and removeElementAt is essentially a stack.

Comment: Some parts of the Java SDK are historical accidents (some would say "mistakes"), left in there mainly because it's very difficult to remove things from a platform.

Comment: As per java doc [https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Stack.html][1],  
'It extends class Vector with five operations that allow a vector to be treated as a stack'. 

So it is not independent stack class. It is vector which has ability to work as **Stack**.

Answer (score 1):

The Stack class represents a last-in-first-out (LIFO) stack of objects. It extends class Vector with five operations that allow a vector to be treated as a stack. The usual push and pop operations are provided, as well as a method to peek at the top item on the stack, a method to test for whether the stack is empty, and a method to searchthe stack for an item and discover how far it is from the top.

When a stack is first created, it contains no items.

A more complete and consistent set of LIFO stack operations is provided by the Deque interface and its implementations, which should be used in preference to this class.